# Property [address] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel

I am working on a project where a number of buildings with certain information are uploaded and retrieved according to needs.
DB table
Property:
colums: id, image, building_type_id(foreign key to building_type table) etc

I want to run a query where the list will be sorted according to building_type

controller:

```
public function index() {
  return view ('pages.index', [
    'duplex' => Property::where('building_type_id', '4'),
    'singleroom' => Property::where('building_type_id', '1')
  ]);
}
```

view:

```
@if($singleroom->count())
  {{ $singleroom->id }}
@else
  no info
@endif
```

I get this error

> Property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.

I searched for similar problems and i saw i have to add `->get()` or `->first()`:

```
'duplex' => Property::where('building_type_id', '4')->get(),
'singleroom' => Property::where('building_type_id', '1')->get()
```

I get this error:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

And I look at the details, I see 200 queries was performed.
I cant figure out how I asked for 200 queries.

Suggestion that I saw was to increase execution time which I find not to be a solution for 200queries.

I have browsed through for solutions to similar problem but there is no solution. I have `ddd()` but didn't get anything.

Comment: Yes, you did forget to include `->get()` (won't work with `->id` later, as `$singleroom` is a Collection, not a single `Property` Model instance) or `->first()` (probably correct, but `->count()` on `->first()` won't work as expected, so drop it in favour of simply `@if($singleroom)`, as `->first()` returns a `Property` Model instance or `null`). I have no idea why that would be executing 200 queries though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `where()` statically on the model, it returns a query builder you can keep tweeking until it is executed. If you call `get()` on a query builder you will get a collection of results. Instead if you call first it will return your model.

Use `first()` call to actually get the model.

```
[
    'duplex' => Property::where('building_type_id', '4')->first(),
    
    'singleroom' => Property::where('building_type_id', '1')->first(),
],
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Please, why is this function giving an error .  Maximum excution time exceeded         public function index()
     {


        return view('property.index',[
            'property'=>Property::where('agent_id', Auth::user()->id)->first()
        ]);
     }

Comment: That error is very generic and be a lot of things behind failing execution time is indication something keeps executing, but most likely something is not working properly as this code can not normally exceed the execution time.